# Update an ASP.Net grid control automatically with database changes from another user

Tags: c#, asp.net, design-patterns

In my ASP.Net application I have several pages that provide a list of items from the database.  Currently we are using an UpdatePanel to refresh the whole list on a certain interval so that changes from other users will be propagated the screen.  Obviously this isn't very efficient and we don't think it will scale well.

What are some other methods for accomplishing this.  Is there a specific pattern for addressing this issue?

Comment: Are you using some sort of cache? If the pages are data driven then refreshing the page should pull the new data in right? Your question needs a bit more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Use a webservice and javascript timeout to update the values in the client, will be much faster

Pon